# Multiple inheritance and pointer implementation

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
namespace Example1 {

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    virtual ~A() {}
private:
    float data_A;
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    virtual ~B() {}
protected:
    float data_B;
};

class Derived : public A, public B {
public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual ~Derived() {}
protected:
    float data_Derived;
};

}

int main (void)
{
using namespace Example1;
B* pb = new Derived;
delete pb;
}
```

`pb` should now point to the `B` part of the `Derived` object.
But the derived object also derives from `A`, means it has `A` sub-object.. and that `A` sub-object should be "first" because the `Derived` class first inherits from `A`.

How does the compiler approves that? what does it add in order to make it work correctly?

and also, how does it free the memory correctly when deleting the object?

Comment: You have created a Derived object, you have also created a pointer to B and you assigned Derived's address to it. These are independent facts. The type of an object is not lost at runtime just because you assign its adress to a pointer of a base type. You can dynamic_cast from B* to Derived* and it will succeed. "How?", you ask. Well, it's "how it shall be done". If the compiler failed to guarantee this, it wouldn't comply with the C++ standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: By magic.

The medium answer is: It's not for you to worry about. The Standard says that this works, and it's up to the compiler to figure out a way to make it work.

The long answer: Since this depends on your compiler, read up your compiler's documentation! Many C++ compilers implement the Itanium C++ ABI, so that's a start. As part of polymorphic inheritance, each class usually has a so-called *vtable*, which stores a bunch of function pointers, but it also stores RTTI information and joined virtual-destruction and memory-deallocation logic. Think about it: `delete pb;` doesn't just have to call the right destructors in the right order, but it also has to pass the *correct* pointer to the deallocation function. All this information is included in the various vtables of the class hierarchy.

Comment: Clarke's 3rd law: *Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.*

Comment: @MatthieuM.: How about "Any C++ feature banned by large companies is indistinguishable from magic"? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph `§10.1/2`

> [Note: The order of derivation is not significant except as specified
>   by the semantics of initialization by constructor (12.6.2), cleanup
>   (12.4), and storage layout (9.2, 11.1). —end note ]

therefore

```
class Derived : public A, public B {
                ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
                  first    second
```

Then calls derived constructor. Also, destructors will invoked in reverse order.

```
Construction
A()
B()
D()

Destruction
~D()
~B()
~A()
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, which class you type first in derived class declaration. "A should be first" is not correct, as they are equally base classes. The only difference is, which constructor / destructor is called first (in the order / reversed order they were declared as base classes).

You can refer to [why multiple inheritance is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406081/why-should-i-avoid-multiple-inheritance-in-c)

Perhaps what could be well suited for you is single inheritance, with B class deriving from A and C deriving from B.

Answer (score 0):

Source from a french site : [C++ FAQ](http://cpp.developpez.com/faq/cpp/?page=heritage#CONSTRUCTEUR_ordre)

> Les constructeurs sont appelés dans l'ordre suivant :
>
> ```
> le constructeur des classes de base héritées virtuellement en profondeur croissante et de gauche à droite ;
> le constructeur des classes de base héritées non virtuellement en profondeur croissante et de gauche à droite ;
> le constructeur des membres dans l'ordre de leur déclaration ;
> le constructeur de la classe.
> ```
>
> Order of constructors' calls :
>
> ```
> base class constructors from virtual inheritance (BFS style and from left to rigth);
> base class constructors from non virtual inheritance (BFS style and from left to rigth);
> instances constructor in the order of their declaration;
> Class constructor
> ```

I'm guessing the destructors' calls order is the reverse of this order.

Answer (score 0):

Since your destructors are (correctly) virtual here, the compiler has no problem at all. It just calls the right destructor (`~Derived()` in this case) and everything works fine.

The standard does not force any implementation, but a popular one used in many computers is a virtual table. All objects that belong to a class with at least one virtual function (as is the case here) have a pointer (`vptr`) to the virtual table (`vtbl`) corresponding to their class. This `vtbl` has references to the correct overrides of all virtual functions for the object class. Here I am talking about dynamic class (i.e.: the real class of the object), not static class (the class of the pointer). In this case:

- The dynamic type of `pb` is `Derived`, since it points to a `Derived` instance
- The static type of `pb` is `B`, since it was declared as `B*`

As you can see, the compiler does not care about the static type in this case. It interprets the instruction `delete pb` as this (pseudocode):

```
pb->vptr->destructor();
operator delete(pb); // Not exactly, but this is immaterial in this case
```

You can disregard the second line for our purposes. The runtime will go through this chain and find the right destructor to call (`Derived()`). `Derived()` will in turn call `~A()` and `~B()` in the right order.

Comment: The correct terminology is that "the static type of `*pb` is `B`, and the dynamic type of `*pb` is `Derived`."

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that it works, but the actual implementation is compiler dependant and you shouldn't rely on the details (but it is still a good thing to keep in mind so you don't make incorrect assumptions when dealing with pointers).

When multiple inheritance is used, simple line such as `B* pb = new Derived` implicitly changes the actual value of the pointer. In this particular case, since the compiler knows it has to convert a `Derived` pointer to `B*`, it knows exactly by how much it needs to change the pointer (e.g. `sizeof(A)`, of course the actual value is probably different).

If you are using virtual inheritance (which is guarantees that a common base class is only included once, e.g. if both `A` and `B` inherited from `CommonBase`), then simple pointer conversion becomes even more complex, and the compiler does a vtable lookup to find the actual offset it should use for pointer conversion.

If you are using Visual Studio, you can make a breakpoint on this line and press Alt+8 to see the disassembly, which will reveal the 'magic' behind pointer conversion.