# How to handle resource management with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance, resource-management

Say I have a base class and some derived classes:

```
class Base1
{
public:
    virtual ~Base1() {}
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class Derive1 : public Base1
{
public:
    void update() override {/*...*/}
};

class Derive2 : public Base1
{
public:
    void update() override {/*...*/}
};
```

and somewhere to manage my derived objects:

```
class Base1Manager
{
public:
    void add(Base1* p)
    {
        objs.push_back(p);
    }
    void update()
    {
        std::for_each(objs.begin(), objs.end(), [](Base1* p) { p->update(); });
    }
    void clear()
    {
        std::for_each(objs.begin(), objs.end(), [](Base1* p) { delete p; });
        objs.clear();
    }
    std::vector<Base1*> objs;
};

Base1Manager bm1;
bm1.add(new Derive1());
bm1.add(new Derive2());
```

I can do update:

```
bm1.update();
```

finally I have to release the resources upon program exit:

```
bm1.clear();
```

The above scenario is fine, but the next is not:

---

The problem is when I add another base class and expand my derived classes:

**NOTE: According to this answer:
[[Why should I avoid multiple inheritance in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406081/why-should-i-avoid-multiple-inheritance-in-c][1]), Point 3 and 4, my `Base1` and `Base2` are different concepts so the multiple inheritance should be fine here.**

```
class Base1
{
public:
    virtual ~Base1() {}
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class Base2
{
public:
    virtual ~Base2() {}
    virtual void do_different_thing() = 0;
};

class Derive1 : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    void update() override {/*...*/}
    void do_different_thing() override {/*...*/}
};

class Derive2 : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    void update() override {/*...*/}
    void do_different_thing() override {/*...*/}
};
```

Also imagine there is a new `Base2Manager`, basically the same as `Base1Manager`.

**Finally my question is, how to properly release the resources?**

Apparently I can not do the release twice:

```
bm1.clear();
bm2.clear();
```

I have to choose only 1 manager and let it do the job, but these 2 managers are made separately and does not know each other, so what's the proper way to handle it?

Would smart pointer help? Should I add an API like `addButNotRelase(Base2* p)` so that I can manipulate `p` but not own `p` (like put `p` in a `vector` other than `objs`?

Comment: Does calling clear only once actually cause any troubles?

Comment: This looks like shared ownership, which should suit `std::shared_ptr`. Or, you could roll your own reference counting if `shared_ptr` is a bad fit.

Comment: @user2040251 the trouble is these managers do not know each other, so it's kinda tricky to decide who should own the resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` helps here as both managers own the (potentially same) pointer.

In your first example, with only one manager, you may have replaced `std::shared_ptr` by `std::unique_ptr`.

If an other class have to own the object to control lifetime, then you may use simple pointer in your manager.

The usage should look like:

```
// The container
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base1>> base1s;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base2>> base2s;

// The objects
std::shared_ptr<Derive1> d1 = std::make_shared<Derive1>();
std::shared_ptr<Derive2> d2 = std::make_shared<Derive2>();

// Feed the containers
base1s.push_back(d1);
base1s.push_back(d2);

base2s.push_back(d1);
base2s.push_back(d2);
```

Comment: If I change to `vector<shared_ptr<Base1>>` and `vector<shared_ptr<Base2>>`, how to assign `new Derive1()` to both of them as a sharing memory? I tried `Derive1* d = new Derive1(); shared_ptr<Base1> p1(d);` but failed to do `shared_ptr<Base2> p2(p1)` cause they are different types. If I do `shared_ptr<Base2> p2(d)` then `p1` and `p2` are not sharing.

Comment: @MarsonMao: Usage example added.

Comment: nice, this one's great, i have to learn more about smart pointer, thanks! ;)