# avoiding trait collisions - use_once?

Tags: php, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two PHP traits that each inherit from the same 3rd trait:

```
trait C {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'c';
    }
}

trait A {
    use C;
    public function ac() {
        echo 'a'.smallTalk();
    }
}

trait B {
    use C;
    public function bc() {
        echo 'b'.smallTalk();
    }
}
```

And I want to use them both in a class:

```
class D {
    use A, B;
    public function acbc() {
        echo ac().bc();
    }
}
```

but I keep getting the error

> Fatal error: Trait method smallTalk has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on D

I know `use_once` is not a thing, but I am looking for the same functionality that `require_once` or `include_once` provides, but for traits. This example is simplified. My real `C` has lots of methods and is inherited by many more than 2 traits, so I don't really want to have to repeat a long string of `insteadof` every time I use more than 1 of these traits.

Comment: short version: No, manually handling collisions is the price for using traits.

Comment: I suspect you are abusing traits. I only use traits as a last resort. This answer has a good explantion on the alternatives (in C++, but they mostly apply to any OOP language) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406081/why-should-i-avoid-multiple-inheritance-in-c#answer-407928

Answer (score 3):

You need read: [Conflict Resolution](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict)

> If two Traits insert a method with the same name, a fatal error is
>   produced, if the conflict is not explicitly resolved.
>
> To resolve naming conflicts between Traits used in the same class, the
>   **insteadof** operator needs to be used to choose exactly one of the
>   conflicting methods.
>
> Since this only allows one to exclude methods, the **as** operator can be
>   used to allow the inclusion of one of the conflicting methods under
>   another name.

Example:

```
<?php
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the question? "My real C has lots of methods and is inherited by many more than 2 traits, so I don't really want to have to repeat a long string of insteadof every time I use more than 1 of these traits." I know I can do what you're saying, but I was asking if there was a _better_ solution.

Comment: You will not be able to resolve the conflict by other means. Use the trait + extended.
If you want to do everything "right" - do not try to do everything with the help of trait.
You can create a class C. D extended from C.
Without a real example - hard to say which architecture will be true.

I recommend to get acquainted with the SOLID. It can assist in selecting the architecture.

Comment: Upvoted because this is the correct answer, even if OP doesn't like that it is the correct answer.

Comment: It's not *really* the correct answer because it ignores the spirit and intent of the original question. The answer is, in php we haven't yet a good solution for handling this. The only solution is per-method aliasing or renaming. There are still short comings in php's trait use; particularly it will attempt to load the same trait in multiple places (use Trait1 in Trait2; then try to use both of those in your class; it should resolve that Trait1 has been included already, but rather, it will fatally conflict).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to avoid writing a lot of code. Basically is to make use of the anonymous class and call the public function that essentially come out from `trait C`.

It may still be depend on how your code is really structured (e.g. are you using `$this`):

```
trait C
{
    public function smallTalk()
    {
        return 'c';
    }
}

trait A
{
    public function ac()
    {
        // anonymous class to avoid leaking all Trait C functions to
        // the classes that didn't sign up for that. Can't see other bad
        // side effects except for being inefficient
        $local_class = new class {
            use C;
        };
        return 'a' . (new $local_class())->smallTalk();
    }
}

trait B
{
    public function bc()
    {
        $local_class = new class {
            use C;
        };
        return 'b' . (new $local_class())->smallTalk();
    }
}
```

So you can now you can include both traits:

```
class D
{
    use A, B;
    public function acbc()
    {
        echo $this->ac() . $this->bc();
    }
}
```