# Multiple Inheritence in c++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Why Multiple Inheritance is **discouraged** in c++? And as we all know java doesn't support Multiple inheritance. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I avoid multiple inheritance in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406081/why-should-i-avoid-multiple-inheritance-in-c)

Comment: Multiple inheritance is not discouraged in C++. There's a great deal of FUD concerning it; people tend to scare themselves when they run into problems, resulting in an irrational reaction. Hmm, I think I may have just explained why it **is** discouraged, but that doesn't make the claimed reasons rational.